# Roll out ExtLib and stuff on a Domino Server

Tags: installation, lotus-domino

Maybe a stupid question but I asked myself if there is a more convienient way to roll out ExtLib, SBT and so on on a Domino Server than just copy the content of all those updatesite.zip to the directory.
The updatesite-way is very cool for the clients but for the server?

I really appreciate your comments & suggestions :-)

Comment: Many thanks to Tode for pointing to the right direction. I summarized everything here for your convenience: http://mardou.dyndns.org/Privat/osnippets.nsf/id/OBUE-98KPB9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with 8.5.3 there is a way to automatically install extlib on servers using an updatesite application. Check [this](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/XPages_Extension_Library_Deployment) for detailled instructions.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for that! BUT: does this mean that the way described here makes domino HTTP task start slowly due to the "dynamic" usage of the extentions? I think there must be a lag against installing the stuff the traditional way. Do you have any experience with that?

Comment: I answer this for myself: Domino will from now on start with this option. A little slower but ok.

Comment: Tode, I experienced that this works only on windows machines. Is there any solutions for linux machines, too?

Comment: Found the reason: it's not Linux at all it's just security settings on the machine, independent from the OS. Make sure the updatesite.nsf can be accessed by the server and let the server be able to execute code as set in the security options of your server document.